# Setting attribute labels programmatically

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes, eav, upgrade-script

I'm trying to set labels for attributes for each language. For example I want to translate Price (in Stores > Attributes > Product > Price > Manage labels) for all the store views.
[image]

However, I can't seem to find a way to do this via UpgradeData.php. I don't want to directly inject with an SQL query. Looking for something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.xx') < 0) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $attributeId = $eavSetup->getAttributeId('catalog_product', 'price');
        $options = [
            'values' => [
                'Dutch(NL)' => 'Prijs',
            ],
            'attribute_id' => $attributeId,
        ];
        $eavSetup->addAttributeOption($options);
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

You can set the frontend labels with the following code in your UpgradeData or InstallData script:

```
    /** @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $attribute = $this->productAttributeRepository->get($attributeCode);
    $sourceModel = $attribute->getSourceModel();
    $frontendLabels = [
        $this->attributeFrontendLabelFactory->create()
            ->setStoreId(1)
            ->setLabel('Label 1'),
        $this->attributeFrontendLabelFactory->create()
            ->setStoreId(2)
            ->setLabel('Label 2'),
    ];
    $attribute->setFrontendLabels($frontendLabels);
    $this->productAttributeRepository->save($attribute);

    if ($sourceModel !== null) {
        $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            $attributeCode,
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\EavAttributeInterface::SOURCE_MODEL,
            $sourceModel
        ); // this is needed as the attribute repository throws away the source model while saving in Magento 2.2.5
    }
```

`$this->eavSetupFactory` is of type `\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory`.

`$this->productAttributeRepository` is of type `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface`.

`$this->attributeFrontendLabelFactory` is of type `\Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeFrontendLabelInterfaceFactory`.

You should inject them via Dependency Injection in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you! I've been also trying to keep the already set labels by getting labels by getFrontendLabels() and appending my store label, and since this function return type is clearly an array 


* @return \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeFrontendLabelInterface[]


I expected an array merge would suffice but kept getting this warning that "array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array", I'm gonna see it through ...

Comment: `$eavSetup->updateAttribute(...)` not needed anymore, at least from Magento 2.3.5 or higher.